# Replace the associated pid (i.e. unregister and register) atomically

Tags: erlang, atomic

Suppose a `Pid` is registered as follows.

```
register(foobar, Pid).
```

Now I want to replace the associated pid:

```
unregister(foobar),
register(foobar, NewPid).
```

How can I achieve this atomically?

Comment: You might serialize requests (e.g. using a gen_server, which exposes an `update_name/2` API). You would perform both operations within a `handle_call`. For this to work, everyone in the system needs to use this API instead of directly calling `register/unregister`.

Comment: @RobertoAloi That's a good idea. But what if my system has to integrate with other systems so I cannot guarantee they are following the same tradition?

Answer (score 1):

Use `gproc`, https://github.com/uwiger/gproc

The advantage is that its registry is an ETS table and ETS tables have atomic updates where you can overwrite a name atomically like the thing you want. I am almost positive it can do this kind of thing.

Comment: I thought of that, but I couldn't find any gproc API allowing that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It may be that it doesn't do it :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, at least, using the `register/2` and `unregister/1` BIFs.
You need to serialize requests to the registry, for example using a `gen_server` or an `ETS table`.

Also, consider the following. Registered names for processes are *atoms* and **atoms, in the Erlang VM, are limited and not garbage collected**. If you're registering/unregistering processes dynamically a huge number of processes (e.g. one process per request) you might want to re-think to this approach, since you might *run out of atoms* at some point.

Comment: Actually I'm having many "clients" referring to a `root_node` which is  `register`ed to some process, which may be changed in runtime.

Comment: Well, how about using `global:set_lock/1`?